# Как убрать пунктирную линию в ComboBoxItem?

Tags: c#, wpf

Как убрать пунктирную линию в ComboBoxItem?
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Она появляеться при нажатии и наведении.

```cs
ComboBox Tables = new ComboBox { FocusVisualStyle = null, HorizontalAlignment = HorizontalAlignment.Stretch, VerticalAlignment = VerticalAlignment.Top, Margin = new Thickness(20, 10, 5, 0) };
Tables.ItemsSource = db.Query<string>("Select [Name] FROM TreeView WHERE Type = 'Table'").ToList();
TabContent.Children.Add(Tables);
```

Использую Dapper для доступа к базе данным.
Так же использую Material Design.

Comment: А с чего вы взяли, что это линия именно ComboBoxItem'a? Это линия выделения, например, через TAB, она есть на любом объекте.

Comment: Ну пунктирная линия фокуса удаляется FocusVisualStyle="{x:Null}", но судя по коду он и так у вас null, так что нужно разобраться, что за линия и почему она пунктирная

Comment: Повторю еще раз, эта линия есть **везде**, у каждого Control'a, понажимайте на TAB и увидите ее еще на сотни других объектах, будете убирать везде? Также, почему вы используете C# для создания UI? В WPF это очень, очень плохая идея. Разбирайтесь со стилями, пишите в XAML стиль для нужного элемента, где устанавливаете `FocusVisualStyle` в `NULL`.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Скорее всего у ComboBoxItem, я думала что можно сделать как-то через DataTemplate.

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Я думала создать DataTemplate в XAML, и задать через c# Combobox.ItemTamplate.

Comment: Вы должны весь UI делать в XAML, не используйте код!)

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Хорошо как это сделать через XAML, убрать пунктирную линию у елементов ComboBox-a?

Comment: Начнем с того, что `new ComboBox..` у вас должно быть в XAML, как `<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding Items}"/>`, строка `Tables.ItemsSource..` должна превратиться в свойство, которое реализует `INotifyPropertyChanged`, ну и про `DataContext` не забудьте. И забудьте вообще про использование контролов, особенно их создание в коде! WPF ценится своими привязками, а вы их игнорируете, зачем вам он тогда, используйте WinForms. Касательно полосы, я вам выше уже сказал, делается это через стили, например, [так](https://pastebin.com/6izTYt7W), но как по мне, это бредовая идея убирать их, ибо они везде...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

В WPF работать напрямую с контролами в C# - плохая практика, минусы данного подхода перечислять не буду, их очень много. Если кратко то сумма этих минусов даст вам в десятки раз больше работы, чем если вдумчиво подойти к вопросу, и использовать XAML и MVVM.

Если кратко, с привязкой данных, не распиливая код на классы (что в будущем рекомендуется сделать), то заведите свойство.

```cs
public sealed partial class MainWindow : Window, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private ObservableCollection<string> _myItems;

    public ObservableCollection<string> MyItems
    {
        get => _myItems;
        set
        {
            _myItems = value;
            OnPropertyChanged();
        }
    }

    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this; // вот это важно, оно указывает, где Binding должен брать данные, как вы уже поняли, оно может указывать куда угодно, следовательно и данные могут быть в отдельном классе, где захотите
    }

    private void MainWindow_Loaded(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e) // в xaml окну добавьте Loaded="MainWindow_Loaded"
    {
        // ... ваш код, выполняемый при запуске приложения
        var items = db.Query<string>("Select [Name] FROM TreeView WHERE Type = 'Table'");
        MyItems = new ObservableCollection(items);
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged([CallerMemberName] string propertyName = null)
        => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
}
```

Далее можете делать с коллекцией `MyItems` что угодно, работать с ней можно почти так же как с `List<string>`. А `ComboBox` будет сам обновляться, когда состав коллекции поменяется, либо она будет заменена на другую, в реальном времени.

Способ привязки данных везде одинаковый, например вы можете точно так же привязать `ComboBox.SelectedItem` к свойству типа `string`. В сеттере можно вызывать свой код, то есть вам в этом случае не понадобится обработчик события `SelectionChanged`. (если надо показать - покажу, напишите об этом в комментарии)

В XAML стиль фокусировки можно об`null`ить так, через `Style`:

```xml
<ComboBox ItemsSource="{Binding MyItems}">
    <ComboBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBox}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
            <Setter Property="HorizontalAlignment" Value="Stretch"/>
            <Setter Property="VerticalAlignment" Value="Top"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,10,5,0"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Style>
    <ComboBox.Resources>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ComboBoxItem}">
            <Setter Property="FocusVisualStyle" Value="{x:Null}"/>
        </Style>
    </ComboBox.Resources>
</ComboBox>
```